# Passing a single character by pointer Vs Passing a string by pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, character, parameter-passing

## Passing a string

```
void foo(char *str)
{
  printf ("\nPassed argument is %s", str);
  strcpy(str,"XYZ");
  printf ("\nChanged argument is %s", str);
}
```

The function calling would be:

```
char abc[10];
strcpy (abc,"ABC");
foo(abc);
printf ("\nNew value of string is %s",abc);
```

The above code works as expected. It works because I passed the string by pointer. Now how would you do the same, if I wanted the function to modify a single character?

```
void foo(char &ch)
{
  printf ("\nPassed argument is %c", ch);
  ch = 'A';
  printf ("\nChanged argument is %c", ch);
}
```

The function calling would be:

```
char c;
c = 'x';
foo(&c);
printf ("\nNew value of character is %c",c);
```

This code doesn't work. I believe its a simple question, but I can't find an answer to it. If I changed the function prototype to `void foo(char *ch)`, then it would expect the address of a string and not a character.

You may ask, why I need to do this and why can't I just make the function return the character! That's one solution, but I would like to know the twisted way also.

Comment: Using the ampersand `&` when declaring a function argument is not valid C, it's C++ and used to mark the argument as a reference and not a pointer. And for that to work you of course can't pass a pointer.

Comment: Also, when you have a pointer, it is the address of some place in memory. If it points to a string or a single character depends on how you treat and use the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not forget that in C a string is just
an array of characters ending with null terminator (0).
So, `char *` is pointer to character.
But due to the way strings are made in C, it can
as well point to a string.

Try this:

```
void foo(char *ch)
{
*ch='a';
}
```

Usage similar like in your question. e.g.,

```
char c;
c = 'x';
foo(&c);
printf ("\nNew value of character is %c",c);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. There are not "strings" in C.
2. `char *` defines a type pointing to a `char`.
3. Whether a function having a `char * p` as argument could expect `p + 1` pointing to valid memory depends on what had been passed to the function as parameter. The function itself knows nothing about this.

Answer (score 1):

`void foo(char &ch)` works only in C++ and not in C atleast until C99 where references are not part of language.

Looking at your usage, I believe you want

```
void foo(char *ch)
{
  *ch = 'A';
}
```

You may find [this](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/) tutorial useful to understand why above argument type and how is it different from string argument. (first version)

Answer (score 0):

Should not the second foo function would be ..

```
    void foo(char *ch)
{
  printf ("\nPassed argument is %c", ch);
  *ch = 'A';
  printf ("\nChanged argument is %c", ch);
}
```

Comment: georgem has already posted code which I missed can you please try it .. I have also edited it